# Crystal report Formula Field Issue

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new to Crystal Report.
Currently I have two Data tables:

```
AssetId     AssetName     AssetDescription
   A1        asset one          Required
   A2        asset two          Required
   A3        asset three        Required
   A4        asset four         Required
   A5        asset five         Required


DeficiencyItemId      AssetId        IsIssueStill
       D1                A1               No
       D2                A1               Yes
       D3                A2               No
```

The second table has a foreign key of AssetId which refers to the table 1 AssetID


In crystal report I outer join two tables. Then I need to create a formula field to handle this logic, for all assets in the table 1(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5) I need to indicate whether contains "**Yes**" DeficiencyItem.
Such as

```
A1  F //(IsIssueStill == Yes)
A2  P //(IsIssueStill == No)
A3  P //(No record in Table 2)
A4  P //(No record in Table 2)
A5  P //(No record in Table 2)

I write a formular 
IF ({DeficiencyItem.IsStillIssue} = No or     IsNull({DeficiencyItem.IsStillIssue}))THEN
    "P"
ELSE "F"
```

but For **A1** there are two DeficiencyItem records, this formula only read the first one so the result is **P**. But what I want is if the Asset has any deficicyitem record whose IsIssueStill == **Yes**, I need the value be **F**.

The second issue is for A4 and A5 they do not have any DeficiencyItem records and I need give the value to **P**.

Can anyone give me a help on achieving this function.

Comment: So what result do you get with your formula.. Also what is the layout of your report? I mean are there any groups or soo

Comment: there is no group in my report. I just need AssetId and P/F to be showed on the report. However the P/F field need to follow the logic I described above

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your report. Your logic looks OK. So should work.. unless you are doing something else.

Comment: Sorry I cannot upload the screenshot, I think the problem may happened because in the second table. The Asset one has two records. The logic may only read the first record and generate the value